# How to use DrawArc in C# correctly from GCODE?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, g-code

I'm trying to draw an arc (using Graphics.DrawArc) from GCode, but the C# result is not the same when i compare with result from https://ncviewer.com/ website.
I changed the coordinate system to start from left buttom.

I'm using the following libraries:
-geometry3sharp
-gsGcode

the GCode:

```
G90 G64 G80 G17 G21 G40 G49 G50 G94
M1221
M5
G0      x25.10430     y35.10093
M4
M1
M3
G2      x33.76455     y20.10093    i0.0000000  j-10.0000000
G2      x25.10430     y35.10093   i-8.6602500    j5.0000000
M5
G0     x100.10430     y50.10093
M4
M1
M3
G1       x0.10430     y50.10093
G1       x0.10430      y0.10093
G1     x100.10430      y0.10093
G1     x100.10430     y50.10093
M5
M30
```

the C# code:

```
else if (gc.type == GCodeLine.LType.GCode && gc.code == 2)
{
    if (gc.parameters[0].identifier.ToUpper() == "X")
        xparam = gc.parameters[0].intValue;
    else
        continue;
    if (gc.parameters[1].identifier.ToUpper() == "Y")
        yparam = gc.parameters[1].intValue;
    else
        continue;
    if (gc.parameters[2].identifier.ToUpper() == "I")
        iparam = gc.parameters[2].intValue;
    else
        continue;
    if (gc.parameters[3].identifier.ToUpper() == "J")
        jparam = gc.parameters[3].intValue;
    else
        continue;

    long x = xparam;
    long y = gbitmap.Height-1 - yparam;

    // GeometryUtils.CalcArc3Points(xstartpos, ystartpos,iparam,jparam, x, y);
    // 
     g3.Arc2d arc = new g3.Arc2d(new g3.Vector2d(iparam, jparam), new g3.Vector2d(xstartpos, ystartpos),new g3.Vector2d(x, y));

     newgraphic.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 1f),(float)arc.P0.x, (float)arc.P0.y, (float)arc.P1.x, (float)arc.P1.x, (float)arc.AngleStartDeg, (float)arc.AngleEndDeg);

    xstartpos = x;
    ystartpos = y;

}
```

GCODE image from MyApp

[image: GCODE image from MyApp]

GCODE image from website

[image: GCODE image from website]

if I change the code from this line:

```
 newgraphic.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 1f),(float)arc.P0.x, (float)arc.P0.y, (float)arc.P1.x, (float)arc.P1.x, (float)arc.AngleStartDeg, (float)arc.AngleEndDeg);
```

to:

```
 newgraphic.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 1f),(float)arc.P0.x, (float)arc.P0.y, (float)arc.P1.x, (float)arc.P1.y, (float)arc.AngleStartDeg, (float)arc.AngleEndDeg);
```

i get the following image:
[Image after code change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wm9t.png)

Comment: The I and J parameters are always incremental, relative from the start point.  So the first argument you pass to the g3.Arc2d() constructor is likely to be incorrect, be sure to add x/ystartpos.  The ystartpos = y; statement cannot be correct, y was mapped to drawing coordinates.  So that probably should ystartpos = yparam.  Lots more iffy details, like not handling G91 and using a field named intValue for a parameter that must be floating point.  Always debug this first with a simple G-code program whose result you can predict on a piece of paper.

Comment: so, this means that my first argument should be (G0x+I,G0y+J)?